# Thread Safe Attributed String Height Calculation

Tags: ios, thread-safety, uikit

How can I calculate the height of an attributed string in a thread safe manner? I am pre-calculating cell heights for a potentially very complex layout and don't want to block the main thread when performing the calculations. Here's what I am doing (simplified for readability):

```
// pre-calculate layout information
- (void)performHeightCalculations:(MFBlock)completion {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

        // ...

        NSDictionary *options = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                          NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)};

        // Height calculation for attributed string
        // Crash: EXC_BAD_ACCESS 0xbadbeef
        label.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                            initWithData:HTMLString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                            options:options
                            documentAttributes:nil
                            error: &err];

        height += [label sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(contentWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)].height;

        // ...

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (completion) {
                completion();
            }

        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apple [does not recommend](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:) calling the above method off the main thread, explanation below:

> The HTML importer should not be called from a background thread (that
>   is, the options dictionary includes NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute
>   with a value of NSHTMLTextDocumentType). It will try to synchronize
>   with the main thread, fail, and time out. Calling it from the main
>   thread works (but can still time out if the HTML contains references
>   to external resources, which should be avoided at all costs). The HTML
>   import mechanism is meant for implementing something like markdown
>   (that is, text styles, colors, and so on), not for general HTML
>   import.

If anybody knows of any alternate methods to handle determining the height on a background thread, I'm still open ears!